# In a finite poset $P$, a down-set $I$ is meet-irreducible $\iff I=P\backslash\uparrow x$ for some $x\in P$

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $P$ be a finite ordered set. Show that a down-set $I$ is meet-irreducible in $\mathcal{O}(P)$, that is $I \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{O}(P))$, if and only if it is of the form $P\backslash\uparrow x$ for some $x\in P$.

Proving that $\forall \,x\in P$ taking $U= \downarrow x$ gives you a join-irreducible element of $\mathcal{O}(P)$ is quite easy, because if you write $I \cup J = \downarrow x $, for some $I, J \in \mathcal{O}(P)$, you have that w.l.o.g. $x \in I$, so $\downarrow x \in I$, that means $\downarrow x = I$. I tried to do something similar for the meet-irreducible elements, but it seems not to lead anywhere.

Comment: For dualizing the join-irred proof, how about this? Let $I\cap J = P - \!\uparrow\!\!x$. Then wlog $x\notin I$, so $\uparrow\!\!x \cap I = \varnothing$. In other words, $I \subseteq P - \!\uparrow\!\!x$, and therefore $P - \!\uparrow\!\!x = I$.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky Why don't you go ahead and answer the question with that comment. It seems perfectly fine.

Comment: I didn't because it doesn't answer the question as asked. But since it's been 2 days with no further clarification, I'll go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer intends to complete [the one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4331314/303170) of [Eric Nathan Stucky](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/600276/eric-nathan-stucky), which proves one of the implications, and I'll refer you to that answer for that part of the exercise ([upvote it and/or mark it as the right answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it helpful), and I'll prove that if $I$ is meet-irreducible, then $I = P \setminus {\uparrow} c$, for some $c \in P$, or equivalently, that if $I$ doesn't have that shape, then $I$ is not meet-irreducible.

Although you don't mention it in your proof of the join-irreducible elements (you only include one implication, just like Eric) you also need to prove that all join-irreducible down-sets have that shape, which you might do starting with the observation that there exist $c_1, \ldots, c_k \in P$, with $c_i\|c_j$ whenever $i\neq j$, such that $I = {\downarrow} c_1 \cup \cdots \cup {\downarrow} c_k$, for every down-set $I$ in a finite poset $P$ (here, $x\|y$ means that $x\nleq y$ and $y\nleq x$, i.e., $x$ and $y$ are incomparable).

Just the same, if $U$ is an up-set, there exist $d_1, \ldots, d_k \in P$ such that $U = {\uparrow} d_1 \cup \cdots \cup {\uparrow} d_k$.
The complement of a down-set is an up-set;
so if $I$ is a down-set, then
$$I = P \setminus U = P \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^k {\uparrow}d_i = \bigcap_{i=1}^k P \setminus{\uparrow}d_i,$$
with $d_i\|d_j$ for $i\neq j$.
Now, either $k=1$ and $I$ has the desired shape, or $k>1$ and clearly $I$ is not meet-irreducible (since it is the intersection of different down-sets larger than $I$).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if this fully addresses your question (as it doesn't answer the question in the title, for instance), but it seems that this should work as a dual to the join-irreducible proof you gave:

> Let $I\cap J=P-\!\uparrow\!\!x$  Then wlog $x\notin I$, so $\uparrow\!\!x\cap I = \varnothing$.
>
> In other words, $I\subseteq P-\!\uparrow\!\!x$ and therefore $P-\!\uparrow\!\!x = I$.

Comment: The question in the title and the body of the post don't coincide, and I think you completely answered the one in the body; +1 for that. If you don't complete the answer in the title (the converse implication) then I'll do it later.

Comment: @amrsa: I'm not planning on working on this further, so go ahead :)